# All requests ends up in GET route. Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, request, laravel-8, laravel-api

I have a Laravel(8.83) application. API routes end up in `GET` requests always.

To check the problem I have deleted all the routes except one. Now I have just one route:

```
Route::put("cart/{id}", function(Request $request, $id) {
    return $request->all();
});
```

Although I make `PUT` request on the postman, the result is: `"The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: PUT."`

[image: Postman Image]

[image]

I have tried `PUT`, `PATCH`, `POST`, `DELETE`, and `OPTIONS`. **All ended up in the same error.**

**Edit: 3 Oct 2022**

- I run `php artisan optimize:clear` and `composer dump-autoload` several times. None resolved the issue.
- The project is in production, deployed on a server. I have made a request from a Vue.JS web app client, and the result is the same. I don't think the problem is caused by Postman.

Comment: Maybe you somewhere overwrite `$_SERVER` to always indicated it's GET request?

Comment: I think solution is in postman. I usually don't use postman so I may be wrong but while sending request there is something form-data or json data. If form-data is selected you have to add _method field as put in post request otherwise it will work directly in put. Something similar we have to change it.

Comment: Please edit the question to demonstrate (only) a put request is emitted - you can do this with curl or by checking the network tab of you browser tools. A common cause is making requests on http which redirects to https (as GET) - or on the wrong hostname or similar.

Comment: did you run "php artisan optimize" ??

Comment: @Justinas I have chacked the files but couldn't find anywhere overwriting the `$_SERVER`.

Comment: @JSTECH The project is in production. I have made a request from a Vue.JS web app client, and the result is the same. I don't think the problem is caused by Postman.

Comment: @boolfalse yes I run `php artisan optimize:clear` and `composer dump-autoload` several times.

Comment: @YasinBARAN, Does it show error when retrying with `Route::get()`?

Answer (score 1):

The request method is probably getting modified in Postman or in webserver config, or in .htaccess.

Here's one thread on a similar issue in Postman - [Postman support](https://support.postman.com/hc/en-us/articles/211913929-My-request-is-redirected-to-a-GET-request)

For a reference to a working .htaccess - [Laravel .htaccess GitHub](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8.x/public/.htaccess)

Comment: The project is in production. I have made a request from a Vue.JS web app client, and the result is the same. I don't think the problem is caused by Postman.

Comment: @YasinBARAN as I commented on the question - it'd be more-than-helpful if you'd edit the question to demonstrate you are actually emitting a PUT request :).